# Using ffmpegFrameRecorder the merged video is short?

Tags: java, android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I am using ffmpegFrameRecorder from JavaCV Api to merge several mp4 videos to one . Here is my code:

```
FrameGrabber grabberlist[] = new FFmpegFrameGrabber[filenamelist
                    .size()];

for (int i = 0; i < grabberlist.length; i++) {

                System.out.println("FILES" + filenamelist.get(i));
                grabberlist[i] = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(filenamelist.get(i));
                grabberlist[i].start();

            }

            FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Apptavia/output.mp4",
                    grabberlist[0].getImageWidth(),
                    grabberlist[0].getImageHeight(), 1);

            recorder.start();

            for (int i = 0; i < grabberlist.length; i++) {

                Frame frame;
                while ((frame = grabberlist[i].grabFrame()) != null) {

                    recorder.record(frame);

                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < audioList.size(); i++) {

                recorder.record(audioList.get(i));
            }

            recorder.stop();

            for (int i = 0; i < grabberlist.length; i++) {

                grabberlist[i].stop();
            }
        }
```

The output video is created but the video length is less . I have debugged the number of frames from .grab() method is less than the total frames. What could be the solution for this . Please help.